# Figuring out a formula

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help figuring out a formula where you multiply a number but each time also adds the result of the previous one.
For example, if I would like to multiply `x*1.5`  3 times and each multiplication considers the previous result I would do something like: `x + (x * 1.5) + ((x * 1.5) * 1.5) + (((x * 1.5) * 1.5) * 1.5)`
Now how would I refactor this formula to do it for `N` times without having to manually brute force all of that?

I'm very bad at math, I know it is something very obvious.

Comment: So you ask for $x\cdot 1.5^0 + x\cdot 1.5^1+x\cdot 1.5^2+x\cdot 1.5^3+\dots+x\cdot 1.5^n$?  Factor out an $x$ and recognize the rest as a geometric series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^N x(1.50^n) = x\sum_{n=0}^N (1.50^n) = x\frac{1-(1.5)^{N+1}}{1-1.5} = 2x(1.5^{N+1}-1).$$

So, three times should give you
$$2x(1.5^4-1) = 8.125x.$$

Comment: Thank you very much that's actually it. One more thing though, if you don't mind, how would I rearrange the equation that you gave me, so that ```x``` is on the left side? So like x = ....